# Why can I not add a "Description" when creating a new Lead from Code?

Tags: leads, java, create-records

I made a small Java Project to connect to Salesforce and get Leads and Create some new. Got into a problem of creating a new Lead with the "description" property even if i saw the property exists in the Lead Object. I don't understand this, really. Am i missing something?

This works:

```
JSONObject lead = new JSONObject();
        lead.put("FirstName", "Mike");
        lead.put("LastName", "Smith");
        lead.put("Company", "test.com");
```

---

This does not work:

```
JSONObject lead = new JSONObject();
        lead.put("FirstName", "Mike");
        lead.put("LastName", "Smith");
        lead.put("Company", "test.com");
        lead.put("Description", "random text here");
```

This is what i can see on debug:

```
[DEBUG] 55:03(Wire.java:wire:72)
http-outgoing-1 << "  "message" : "No such column 'Description' on sobject of type Lead",[\n]"

[DEBUG] 55:03(Wire.java:wire:72)
http-outgoing-1 << "  "errorCode" : "INVALID_FIELD"[\n]"
```

But i looked in the Lead object properties. It's there.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Check FLS for description in your SFDC instance?

Answer (score 0):

I googled it more and finally found an [explanation](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000159jdAAA). I cannot add a Description to a view because it's limit length is too long. Ugh. Not cool.

Comment: ?  this answer doesn't seem related to the OP's question that is about inserting a Lead record with a value for Description field.

Comment: Also link only responses are brittle and frowned upon.